# Effect as seen on BlackNegative - "What's Hot" page

Tags: jquery, css, html

I was wondering on how to do the effect as seen on BlackNegative - http://blacknegative.com/#!/news/
Im talking about "What's Hot" page. Can you do it with only css3, or jQuery, if so, how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be able to help
but for next section using the navigation not to drag the cursor like in BlackNegative

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/